# Unable to save an unshared version of Excel workbook using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to save a version of a shared excel file every time the file is saved. I want the file to be unshared and have no VBA macros. The code I am currently using is as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim x As String, y As String, z As String
x = "Enable Autosave"
y = Now()
z = "C:\Users\.....\MTMtest-" & Format(y, "mm-dd-yy hhmm") & ".xls"

If Sheet3.Cells(1, 5).Value = x Or Sheet4.Cells(1, 5).Value = x Or Sheet5.Cells(1, 5).Value = x Or Sheet6.Cells(1, 5).Value = x Then

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (z)

    If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
        Application.Workbooks.Open (z)
        Workbooks("MTMtest-" & Format(y, "mm-dd-yy hhmm") & ".xls").Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

When I save the shared file, I get a popup asking if I would like to remove the workbook from shared use. When I click yes, I'm given an error: Run-time error '1004' Microsoft Excel cannot access the file. Clicking End gets me an unshared copy, but it is still open.

After I close the copy and attempt to close the original I get the error: The file is locked. This forces me to close the original with task manager.

My question is: How do i get this program to just save a non-macro, non shared copy of my current workbook?

Comment: I am trying to figure this out, but Microsoft says you can't have code or macros in a shared file. If I convert my test file to a shared file, all my code is deleted. Am I missing something?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn: `but Microsoft says you can't have code or macros in a shared file.` Where does it say that? :)

Comment: @jPetersen: Which Office version are you working on? The reson you are getting that error is because when you are using `.SaveCopyAs`, even the `BeforeSave` macro is getting copied across.

Comment: If you have office 2007+ then instead of using `.SaveCopyAs`, you can actually save it as `.xlsx` using `.SaveAs`

Comment: @SiddharthRout My bad... when converting, it deleted all my code; then found MS link that said '... won't be able to add or change ... macros...'. Still trying to figure how to add the code back. Sorry...

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn: When you share a workbook, the code doesn't get deleted. You just can't view it. To view the code, you will have to unshare the workbook :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'm using Office 2010. Will using '.SaveAs' get rid of the macro that is being transferred to the new file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lack of a better alternative, you could save your workbook as a Macroenabled workbook with the savecopyas method in a first place - then open this copy and save as macrofree workbook thanks to the saveas method, and delete the copy.

For some reasons that I couldn't properly articulate it seems to be an issue to use the saveas method on the original workbook directly in this context - in particular this triggers for the original workbook to close in the middle of the BeforeSave event and before the workbook actually gets a chance to get saved. The go-between copy I suggest above is a workaround for that.

Check out this code which works from an Open XML macro enabled workbook - seems to work fine on my end.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim wb As Workbook

    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\backup.xlsm"

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\backup.xlsm")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    wb.SaveAs filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\backup.xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, AccessMode:=xlExclusive

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    wb.Close

    Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & "\backup.xlsm"

End Sub
```

Comment: I actually did end up saving the copy as a .xlsm. I added `Application.EnableEvents = False` as the first line in the Sub, which got rid of the lousy save loop I was getting. I also ended up adding `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` just before making the copy unshared. To get rid of the macro in the copy I found a sub from www.cpearson.com called DeleteAllVBACode and used that.